# Using `\` instead of `/` in Julia

Tags: julia

For scalars, the `\` (solve linear system) operator is equivalent to the division operator `/`. Is the performance similar?

I ask because currently my code has a line like

```
x = (1 / alpha) * averylongfunctionname(input1, input2, input3)
```

Visually, it is important that the division by `alpha` happens on the "left," so I am considering replacing this with

```
x = alpha \ averylongfunctionname(input1, input2, input3)
```

**What is the best practice in this situation, from the standpoint of style and the standpoint of performance?**

Here are some perplexing benchmarking results:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools
[ Info: Precompiling BenchmarkTools [6e4b80f9-dd63-53aa-95a3-0cdb28fa8baf]

julia> @btime x[1]\sum(x) setup=(x=rand(100))
  15.014 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
56.23358979466163

julia> @btime (1/x[1]) * sum(x) setup=(x=rand(100))
  13.312 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
257.4552413802698

julia> @btime sum(x)/x[1] setup=(x=rand(100))
  14.929 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
46.25209548841374
```

They are all about the same, but I'm surprised that the `(1 / x) * foo`  approach has the best performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalar `/` and `\` really should have the same meaning and performance. Let's define these two test functions:

```
f(a, b) = a / b
g(a, b) = b \ a
```

We can then see that they produce identical LLVM code:

```
julia> @code_llvm f(1.5, 2.5)
;  @ REPL[29]:1 within `f'
define double @julia_f_380(double %0, double %1) {
top:
; ┌ @ float.jl:335 within `/'
   %2 = fdiv double %0, %1
; └
  ret double %2
}

julia> @code_llvm g(1.5, 2.5)
;  @ REPL[30]:1 within `g'
define double @julia_g_382(double %0, double %1) {
top:
; ┌ @ operators.jl:579 within `\'
; │┌ @ float.jl:335 within `/'
    %2 = fdiv double %0, %1
; └└
  ret double %2
}
```

And the same machine code too. I'm not sure what is causing the differences in `@btime` results, but I'm pretty sure that the difference between `/` and `\` is an illusion and not real.

As to `x*(1/y)`, that does not compute the same thing as `x/y`: it will be potentially less accurate since there is rounding done when computing `1/y` and then that rounded value is multiplied by `x`, which also rounds. For example:

```
julia> 17/0.7
24.28571428571429

julia> 17*(1/0.7)
24.285714285714285
```

Since floating point division is guaranteed to be correctly rounded, doing division directly is always going to be more accurate. If the divisor is shared by a lot of loop iterations, however, you can get a speedup by rewriting the computation like this since floating-point multiplication is usually faster than division (although timing my current computer does not show this). Be aware that this comes at a loss of accuracy, however, and if the divisor is not shared there would still be a loss of accuracy and no performance gain.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any thoughts on the question of style?

Comment: I kind of like using `alpha \ (longer expression)` but some people might find it confusing, so it seems a bit subjective. I would say use it if you like it and find it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know, but I can suggest you to try using BenchmarkTools
> package: it can help you to evaluate the performance of the two
> different statements. [Here](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) you can find more details.  Bye!

I think that the best choice is `(1/x)*foo` for two reasons:

1. it has the best performance (although not much compared to the other ones);
2. it is more clear for another person reading the code.